# Event to use when order comment is post

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I am using custom module and **want to send order comment data when comment is added to order.** Can you please let me know which event will be useful for after add comment. I am using Third party API and want to send data to other website so I need exact event which will work better

Comment: but there is no solution my question is like that

Comment: It's the same question and the answer is straightforward: Use "sales_order_status_history_save_after". If you need to know more, please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sales_order_status_history_save_before` or `sales_order_status_history_save_after` and you will get the comment you are saving as an object using `$observer->getEvent()->getStatusHistory()`

Comment: I tried $observer->getEvent()->getStatusHistory(), but the output only shows "Object", not the text from the comment I just added. Did I miss anything?

Comment: see what that object contains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following event: `controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_addComment`

In your observer you can then retrieve the comment post by calling:

```
$comment = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getParam('comment');
```