# Magento 1.9.3 Get Last Order Comment After Event sales_order_status_history_save_after

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, history

I have created my own function which is trigged for the event **sales_order_status_history_save_after**. What I wanted to do is, when a new comment is added, the system will get the latest order comment, and send it to customer.

I have tried using the following code,

```
    public function CommentSaveAfter()
    {
            $history = $order->getStatusHistoryCollection()->getFirstItem();
            return $history->getComment();

    }
```

However, this code only get me the last comment before the new one is added.

See screenshot, the code only get the last comment 4444, not 5555 when I click on "**Submit Comment**"
[image]

How can I get the latest comment when click on Submit Comment with  event **sales_order_status_history_save_after** ?

---

This question is not duplicated with [Magento event for adding order comment](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25216/magento-event-for-adding-order-comment)

My problem is I can not get the comment I just added to the order comment, but only the latest comment from status_history. I have already managed to add my own function to the event sales_order_status_history_save_after. So it's different from the other question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento event for adding order comment](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25216/magento-event-for-adding-order-comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Event to use when order comment is post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121967/event-to-use-when-order-comment-is-post/121973)

You can use `sales_order_status_history_save_before` or `sales_order_status_history_save_after`and you will get the comment you are saving as an object using

```
 $observer->getEvent()->getStatusHistory()
```

Comment: I just tried this code, the output is only a "Object". did I miss anything?

Comment: use ->getData() on obejct

Comment: @PadhiyarGaurang any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/298382/57334

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that your collection is already loaded. I don't know if `$order->getStatusHistoryCollection()` returns a cached collection or not. Otherwise you could try resetting/reloading the collection:

```
$collection = $order->getStatusHistoryCollection();
$collection->resetData();
```

Haven't tested it since I haven't touched Magento 1 in almost 2 year now.